# iterate through RAM using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I want to create a program that can iterate through all the addresses in RAM using pointers. Can I do something like the following?

```
int *thePointer = 0x000000; 
//int for 32bit os.

while(thePointer! = 0xFFFFFF){

    std::cout << *thePointer << ' --- ' << thePointer << endl;
    thePointer++;

}
```

If this is possible, how can I initialize my pointer with the starting address in RAM? And how to actually loop through all the addresses until the last address in RAM?

Comment: It is probably worth reading about [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), as that will probably affect your plans.

Comment: Do you want to itereate through the virtual address space of the process doing this? Or do you need to iterate through phsyical memory? The latter might be possible on certain "small" embedded environments. In that case provide more info on your environment please.

Comment: You need to learn some basics of operating system and virtual memory, and what a segmentation fault is.

Comment: C++ doesn't allow this, it is UB. You really should mention your implementation, as what you are trying to do is highly implementation specific.

Comment: Is this speculative? What happened when you tried?

Comment: @Yunnosch yeah.. this is speculative.. i just want to know if this is possible.. by the way thanks for mentioning about virtual and physical address..

Comment: @Rakete1111 what do you mean by UB?

Comment: @glennmark That's undefined behavior and when it happens, the standard makes no guarantees on what would happen if you execute the resulting program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operating systems and runtime environments have grown up a lot since the good old days of the 1980s family computer where such a technique was perfectly possible: a few of the computer game cheat pokes from that era were mine.

C++ only allows you to access memory that you explicitly own. The behaviour on attempting to access any other memory is undefined. Formally you are not allowed to even *set* a pointer to a memory location that you don't own, other than `nullptr` and one past the end of an array or one past the address of a scalar.

You would have to achieve your aims at a far lower level than merely writing a program. Building your own operating system kernel would be one way.

Comment: wow! you're a legend. what do you mean by building my own operating system kernel? does softwares like cheat engine works that way?

Comment: @glennmark: It's a long, long road. I'd go the linux route if I were you, and there are open source versions written in C. I think cheat engines these days exploit backdoors that are intentionally left behind by the game devs.